# Manipulation of text in legend for ggvis

Tags: r, legend, ggvis

I am trying to modify the text that I qet in my ggvis legend. I have a number of time series identified by the variable acronym (which is a string converted into factor). I also have a full name of the items (as title) in the data frame.

```
 ggvis(~Year, ~value, stroke = ~acronym) %>% layer_text(text:=~acronym) %>% layer_points() %>%  group_by(acronym) %>% layer_paths()
```

I would like to show, in the legend, the title corresponding to the acronym (which is used to label the points in the graph, as it is very dense). Ideally, I would

```
 paste(acronym,title,sep=" - ")
```

if it was possible. I have attempted to use labels and values in

```
 add_legend("stroke",title = "Title")
```

but without success.

Comment: to be more specific, I tried seting the vaues and labels parameter in the add_legend() function. I also tried properties=add_props()... but to no avail. I did not find documentation on this anywhere...